# ReactJS: Fetching GET method with Bearer authorization

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, postman, bearer-token

I have Express API with routes. Now i'm connecting client side to the server.

In React I completed Login request (receiving Bearer token). Now I'm trying to make GET Authorizated request, and I get 401 Unauthorized from the server. From Postman everything is ok. I have CORS extension in google Chrome.

Server Route:

```
router.get('/tasks', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    await req.user.populate('tasks').execPopulate()
    res.send(req.user.tasks)
} catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send()
}
```

login request which is OK.

```
handleLogInClick = (email, password) => {
    console.log("Trying to login ");
fetch("http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
  // mode: "no-cors",
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ email: email, password: password }),
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((data) =>
    this.setState({
      data,
    }),
  );
this.getTasks("eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9");
```

};

I know the token, so I tried to get response from the server passing him to the function. I tried some options in headers, but i failed.
The metod getTasks, whih has 401 error below

```
getTasks = (token) => {
token = "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZGNmZjFhMjQzZWUwNTJmNmNkMjAzYzgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzM5ODEwODV9.qUY8RCpc6ABRX7qPw_ea8lKaFg9xDRw2fkiVne1L-s4";

fetch("http://localhost:3000/tasks", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: {
    Accept: "application/json, text/plain, */*",
    // "Content-Type": "application/json",
    Authorization: "Bearer " + token,
  },
})
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then(
    (tasks) =>
      this.setState({
        tasks,
      }),
    console.log(token),
  );
```

};

request from Postman with options:

GET /tasks HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3000
: ,
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZGNmZjFhMjQzZWUwNTJmNmNkMjAzYzgiLCJpYXQiOjE1NzM5ODEwODV9.qUY8RCpc6ABRX7qPw_ea8lKaFg9xDRw2fkiVne1L-s4
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.19.0
Accept: */*
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: b209d7ee-e254-4594-9616-93ebc86bea99,8e867f14-1d0e-40b5-8f85-76a0d317af84
Host: localhost:3000
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: keep-alive
cache-control: no-cache

Thanks in advance for Your help.

Comment: try 
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.set('Authorization', "Bearer " + token);
myHeaders.set('Acccept', "application/json");
myHeaders.set('Acccept', "text/plain");

and then use myHeaders for headers in the fetch:

fetch("http://localhost:3000/tasks", {
  method: "GET",
  mode: "no-cors",
  headers: myHeaders
})